# Looping through a global array and adding event listener to document

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

I'm sure this is a scope or iterator closure issue, but I just can't make it work. Apologies in advance if this is an incredibly obvious fix.

This is a custom HTML tag in GTM. The idea is to listen for WPCF7 (WordPress Contact Form 7) form submission events and push a corresponding event to the GTM dataLayer.

```
//Event listener array
var listeningEvents = [
    ["wpcf7mailsent","CF7formSubmitAndSent"],   //Mail sent successfully
    ["wpcf7submit","CF7formSubmit"],            //Form submitted
    ["wpcf7spam","CF7formSpam"],                //Form spam
    ["wpcf7invalid","CF7formInvalid"],          //Form invalid
    ["wpcf7mailfailed","CF7formMailFail"]       //Form fail
];

//Loop through event listener array & action
for( var i = 0; i < listeningEvents.length; i++){
    document.addEventListener( listeningEvents[i][0],
        (function(i, event, listeningEvents) {
            dataLayer.push({
                'event' : listeningEvents[i][1]
            });
        })() 
    );
}
```

I've been debugging with a console.log just before dataLayer.push. listeningEvents[i][1] inside the addEventListener is coming up as undefined.

I've tried following some advice here:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem

But I keep getting the undefined error.

I really don't want to add the event listener separately 5 times. I really want to be able to expand the event listener list for future maintainability.

**[EDIT]**

I think I found a working solution here:
https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=138763

```
var stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i=0; i<stuff.length; i++)

{

  var closureMaker = function(line) {

    return function(event){ alert(line); };

  };

  var closure = closureMaker( stuff[i] );

  addEventListener('click', closure, false);

}
```

$i wasn't my problem anymore - it was accessing my global array from inside addEventListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a working solution here:
https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=138763

```
var stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i=0; i<stuff.length; i++)

{

  var closureMaker = function(line) {

    return function(event){ alert(line); };

  };

  var closure = closureMaker( stuff[i] );

  addEventListener('click', closure, false);

}
```

$i wasn't my problem anymore - it was accessing my global array from inside addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with your code is that "i" is a parameter in a function.

Don't access "i" directly inside, instead pass it as function params, as shown below.

If you access "i" directly, you will get the last value of "i" due to closure problems.

```
for( var i = 0; i < listeningEvents.length; i++){
    document.addEventListener( listeningEvents[i][0],
      (function(i, event, listeningEvents) {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event' : listeningEvents[i][1]
        });
      })(i) 
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I've implemented your recommendation (very helpful to know, thanks).

Looking at the debug, I think it's having difficult accessing $listeningEvents. I can't see why that would be - everything is global!